# First impressions count

Tags: knowledge, visual

Insert four letters, which represent a place, to create what may be seen in that place.

> N E T
>     N E T

Comment: geography tag needed?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton, not geographical (I edited in the knowledge tag earlier as it uses  knowledge (though not obscure) of a specific subject, and removed the rebus tag as it doesn't use that kind of additional trickery.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the letters to insert are

> **MOMA**, as in Museum of Modern Art. The words then become MONET and MANET, whose paintings would be showcased in such a museum. The title also confirms this, as both Monet and Manet were *Impressionists*.

Comment: Brilliant revival :) Great answer! +1

Comment: Spot on! I was concerned the question was too light.  Really happy it's found, and a good week for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is what you mean, but

> If i add the place "WORK" then I may see a NETWORK at WORK

And

> First impressions count at work (interviews)

But

> It doesn't explain the two NETs nor the visual tag